# How to unset CSS class for menus in the template.php?

Tags: theming

Lets say I have a menu block in my header region. And by default Drupal gives *.active* class for links that are active. I need to get rid of that *.active* class, because the CSS/HTML version of the theme (which I am porting to Drupal 7) doesn't have *.active* class and its not just *.active*, there are many more.

I need this because now default Drupal rules like *a.active* overrides my themes CSS of a simple *a* rule.

Please, do not recommend *!important*.

Comment: isn't it template.php adding this class to the menu item ?

Comment: I am developing a theme from scratch and my theme's template.php is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override a core stylesheet, add it to your theme .info file.

That way, the `.active` class need have no CSS rules

e.g: `themename.info`

```
stylesheets[all][] = system-menus.css
```

> To override a core or contributed module style sheet, it must be
>   specified in your theme's .info file. Drupal overrides are cascading
>   and your theme's stylesheets override any that were previously
>   declared. For example, system-menus.css is located at
>   "modules/system/system-menus.css". If you place a file with the same
>   name in your theme's folder and add the following entry to the .info
>   file, the original system-menus.css file will be ignored and your
>   version will be loaded in its place.

More info here: http://drupal.org/node/263967

See also [hook_css_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7) for a code-based solution to remove stylesheets.

Comment: I want to unset a CSS rule, ID, class - not the entire stylesheet. Maybe if it is not possible to do that maybe it is possible to rename a class? for example rename default li.last classes to li.latest?